# update all values from different table that has same id

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables named `sales` and `rsales`

I have this ff value for table `sales`

```
id | pcode | total | discount |
2  |  33   |  100  |   20     |
3  |  33   |  100  |   20     |
```

and i have this ff value for table `rsales`

```
id | pcode | total | discount | sales_id |
4  |  33   |  100  |   20     |    1     |
5  |  33   |  100  |   20     |    2     |
6  |  33   |  100  |   20     |    3     |
```

My problem is that when I update all values from table `sales`, the table `rsales` must be update either if `sales.id` is equal to `sales_id`.
so for example if I have updated table `sales` with `id` = 2 and 3, the `sales_id` 2 and 3 from `rsales` must be updated either.
take note : only 2 and 3 because only that `id`s is found in table `sales` `id`s.

I have this ff codes so far to update table `rsales`. but the output is shown not as what I meant. it update all values.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE sales AS t1, rsales AS t2
    SET t1.total = '$total_discount',
    t2.total = '$total_discount',
    t2.discount = '$tot'
    WHERE t1.pcode = '$pcode'");
```

Comment: Obligatory: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: You're missing parts of my last answer :P

Comment: if $pcode has the value 33 and your column pcode only has values with 33 then your database is correct...

Comment: Check his history-this guy will ask the same question over and over with slight variations.

Comment: no, i tried adding 

WHERE t1.pcode = '$pcode'
AND t2.pcode = t1.pcode

but it update only sales_id 2 from tbl rsales 3 must be incuded to update

Comment: sorry sir am just really new to php and getting familiar the inner join my question befor is slightly different from the old one. try to check and read it carefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add to the WHERE class the common column between the tables.

```
UPDATE sales AS t1, rsales AS t2
  SET
    t1.total = '$total_discount',
    t2.total = '$total_discount',
    t2.discount = '$tot'
WHERE
    t1.id = t2.sales_id AND
    t1.pcode = '$pcode'
```

Note: I haven't tested it.